# 3D turntable-like reconstruction of an object in refractive environment

Tags: opencv, 3d, computer-vision

I am trying to figure out possible strategies to deal with the following problem: we are given an object whose shape has to be measured based on a number of images taken of the object. Let's say that we take these images by a commercial camera (whose intrinsic parameters are known) that moves on a circular path around the object. We make about 20 pictures. As far as I understand, this is usually referred to as "turntable"-like shape reconstruction.

This is so far easy, as there are many methods that are able to process turntable images and convert them into 3D point clouds. (e.g [this](https://www.utc.fr/~vfremont/dokuwiki/_media/en/pub_2_ieee_ccis04.pdf) or [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.58.1172&rep=rep1&type=pdf) ) These methods are based on the observation that in a turntable setting, every point moves along a circular path (except those on the axis of rotation) which projects as a conic onto each camera - this helps in designing efficient algorithms that recover the camera extrinsics.

Now comes the twist: what if the said object is located in a water container, that has a cylindrical shape? (The camera is outside the container.) Obviously, most of the concepts of projective geometry do not hold anymore - light does not propagate on a straight path, but refracts on the interfaces of water-glass-air.

Thus, I guess the methods listed above would fail, because the basic assumptions are simply not true. Is there any work done in this direction? What would be your strategy or approach to tackle this problem?

I guess the whole system should be "calibrated" somehow, in that we first make pictures of a known calibration geometry placed in the water tank- this way we would get the radius of the path of the camera, and maybe the location, orientation, thickness of the water tank. But how would I do that? I cannot use projective geometry anymore, right? Should it work with some kind of ray-casting approach? Is there any literature on problems similar to this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: "Obviously, most of the concepts of projective geometry do not hold anymore - light does not propagate on a straight path, but refracts on the interfaces of water-glass-air." You already know in what angle the light refracts on the glass water air interface from physics. So you know the position of the water container and the "false" angle of the object in that container and the "true" angle from physics, so you can reconstruct every dimension using the suitable projection matrix.